# How to run QT app with specific theme on Manjaro KDE

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, kde-plasma, manjaro

How i run a QT app with a specific theme on Manjaro KDE?
Exec=QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=Breeze not working.
There's another equivalent to variable GTK_THEME?